# Some children processes do their job several times

Tags: c, linux, fork

I wrote a program that creates 3 children for a process.
Then, each children create 3 processes as well.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define GENERACIONES 2

void crearHijo(int, int);

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        crearHijo(i, 1);

    return 0;
}

void crearHijo(int hijoNum, int gen)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int i, hijos = 3;

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        exit(-1);                       
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Soy de la generación %d, hijo # %d, PID: %d, PPID: %d\n",
                 gen, hijoNum, getpid(), getppid());

        if (gen < GENERACIONES)
        {
            gen++;
            /*srand(time(NULL));
            hijos = rand() % 3 + 1;*/

            for (i = 1; i <= hijos; i++)
                crearHijo(i, gen);
        }

        exit(0);
    }
    else
        waitpid(pid, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I'm expecting 3 sons and 9 grandsons.
But I get the following output:

```
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 1, PID: 2533, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 1, PID: 2534, PPID: 2533
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 1, PID: 2533, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 2, PID: 2535, PPID: 2533
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 1, PID: 2533, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 3, PID: 2536, PPID: 2533
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 1, PID: 2533, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 2, PID: 2537, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 1, PID: 2538, PPID: 2537
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 2, PID: 2537, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 2, PID: 2539, PPID: 2537
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 2, PID: 2537, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 3, PID: 2540, PPID: 2537
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 2, PID: 2537, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 3, PID: 2541, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 1, PID: 2542, PPID: 2541
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 3, PID: 2541, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 2, PID: 2543, PPID: 2541
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 3, PID: 2541, PPID: 2532
Soy de la generación 2, hijo # 3, PID: 2544, PPID: 2541
Soy de la generación 1, hijo # 3, PID: 2541, PPID: 2532
```

Some entries are duplicated and I don' understand why.
There are not more than 12 processes but some of them print the output several times.
How can I avoid this behavior?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your:

```
waitpid(pid, NULL, NULL);
```

is done on the child process, the function returns and the main's

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
```

is continued

Try something like this:

```
    int main()
{
    int i;
    bool j = true;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
       if (j == true)
        j = crearHijo(i, 1);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool crearHijo(int hijoNum, int gen)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int i, hijos = 3;

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        exit(-1);                       
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Soy de la generación %d, hijo # %d, PID: %d, PPID: %d\n",
                 gen, hijoNum, getpid(), getppid());

        if (gen < GENERACIONES)
        {
            gen++;
            /*srand(time(NULL));
            hijos = rand() % 3 + 1;*/

            for (i = 1; i <= hijos; i++)
                crearHijo(i, gen);
        }

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, NULL);
        return (false);
    }
 return (true);
}
```

Comment: OK, I understand the problem. Thanks. :)